# Easier way to create alternate-file?

Tags: navigation

I use switching between alternate-files in VIM a lot in my development workflow and it works great.

However, sometimes I feel that it will be very useful if I could create missing alternate files, so I wonder is there any way to easier perform Step 4 in the following example:

1. Given I have opened a file app/services/some_service.rb
2. And I'm trying to switch to alternate-file by pressing a binding.
3. VIM says:

   E345: Can't find file "/project_path/spec/services/some_service_spec.rb" in
       path
4. I have to navigate to the path and create this file manually, which is time-taking.

Comment: What keys are you pressing? I would expect that from `gf` but not `:e #`